# Sudoku (Assigning values to the grid object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So to explain my attempt, I have a sudoku grid styled with css, and with some of the grids initialized with values. Then for any grids that don't have a value I am dynamically setting an 'input' box.

The part where I am stuck is how do I go about setting the values to the 'grid[]' object, only after all the values have been filled in the sudoku.

Is this is a right approach, how do I check that all the 'td' elements have an innerHTML value set to it and then initialize those values to the 'grid[i][j]'.

HTML

```
<table id="grid">
    <tr class="row">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row">
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table{
    margin: 1em auto;
}

    tr:first-child{
        border-top:solid;
    }

    tr:nth-child(3n) td{
        border-bottom: solid;
    }

    td{
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        border: 1px solid;
        text-align: center;
    }

    td:first-child{
        border-left: solid;
    }

    td:nth-child(3n){
        border-right: solid;
    }

    td input{
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
    }
```

JavaScript

```
window.onload = function(){
    var grid = [];
    var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var prop in obj){
        if(obj[prop].innerHTML == ''){
            obj[prop].innerHTML += '<input id="value" type="text" value="'+ obj[prop].innerHTML+'" />'
        }
    }
    setValues(grid);
};

function setValues(grid){
    for(var i =0; i < 9; i++){
        for(var j =0; j < 9; j++){
           grid[i][j] = '';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think your approach should be exactly reverse of what you're taking now. You should first allot proper values to grid[i][j], and after that from those values should you allot to <td> element of <table>

Comment: @Rdx why is that? what if user is provided with a sudoku and he has to input the values initially and then check to see if it is right